# Changing the AppExchange listing

Tags: api, appexchange, metadata

Can we change the AppExchange listing from public to private and private to public anytime?

We have just released a product, and we would like to keep it private till 10 customers are using this product in production.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change your listing at will without consequence. The security review only allows sanctioned installs of your app, but says nothing about if you're to be publicly listed, nor is publicly listing a requirement for your app to pass security review. You can change this from the AppExchange Publisher Console at any time.